# How to pass Value of user defined datatype in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server-2012, user-defined-types

I have created a user defined datatype in sql server as shown below.

```
CREATE TYPE MonthFees AS TABLE 
(
    MonthID INT, MonthName VARCHAR(20)
)
```

And i created a parameter for that datatype as shown,

```
@MinthFeeDetails MonthFees READONLY
```

now i don't know how to pass the value from sql management studio for that parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/bb510489.aspx) Something like this

```
/* Declare a variable that references the type. */  
DECLARE @mf AS MonthFees;  

/* Add data to the table variable. */  
INSERT INTO @mf (MonthID, MonthName)  
    SELECT MonthID, MonthName 
    FROM table_name;  

/* Pass the table variable data to a stored procedure. */  
EXEC usp_myprocedure @mf;
```